# Internal mechanism of TreeViewer for updte

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp

I am new to SWT and RCP I am trying to use TreeViewer.

By referring to some documents, I came to know there is method:

```
treeViewer.Updte(Object , Properties).
```

I need to know how SWT figure out which data is for which field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is called `update`:

```java
public void update(Object element, String[] properties)
```

Here `element` must be an object that equals one of the objects returned by the content provider for the tree.

If you have called

```java
treeViewer.setUseHashlookup(true);
```

then a hash table (similar to `HashMap`) is used to find the tree element corresponding to the element. Otherwise the tree is just searched exhaustively to find the element.